# 2-Dimensional Pagination in NoSQL Databases without graph support like Couchbase

Tags: pagination, couchbase

I need to know if there are efficient ways to populate 2-Dimensional data from Couchbase with pagination.

I am developing a hierarchical (graphical) response from the database which can grow either ways in depth and breadth (hundreds of nodes each side). I need to return the data with pagination preferably supportable on both sides like depth and breadth level. For example, if depth is passed as parameter, then search the DB in depth direction (DFS) and if breadth is given, then search breadth first (BFS).

Any suggestions are welcome!